# TIKZ: Get Height of Current Node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm creating the following node:

```
\node [style=Rectangle, label={[yshift=0.2cm]left:\tiny(1)}] (1) at
  (-5, 3) {Nuclear Production\\ Into Fuel Salt};
```

See were it says

```
yshift=0.2cm
```

What I want to do is have this get the height of the current node and divide it by 2, that way the label position is always aligned to the top of the node and to the left of it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide MWE (Minimal working Example), a small but complete document which we can copy and test on ours computers. On first sight seems to be a solution to define anchor for label (`south east`) and positioned it on `above left` ... but this should be tested by your MWE :-).

Comment: just correct my first comment: label positioned with `north west`, i.e.  `label={[anchor=south east,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt]north west:(1)}`.

Comment: you can try `label={[above]180  :\tiny(1)}`.

Comment: Note that [label] is actually implemented as a separate node.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! It is arguably easier to define your own label style than measuring the height.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Rectangle/.style={rectangle,draw,align=center},
plabel/.style={append after command={node[anchor=south east,font=\tiny,inner
sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (\tikzlastnode.north west){#1}}}]
\node [style=Rectangle, plabel={(1)}] (1) at
  (-5, 3) {Nuclear Production\\ Into Fuel Salt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me convert my comments to an answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, align=center,
        label={[anchor=south east,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt]north west:(1)}
        ]
        {Nuclear Production\\ Into Fuel Salt};
\end{tikzpicture}

% or shorter, by defining a node style "box"

\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, align=center,
              label={[anchor=south east,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt]north west:#1}
              }
                    ]
  \node[box=(1)] {Nuclear Production\\ Into Fuel Salt};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both examples gives the same result:

[image]